# Startg the Arduino2 with the boards parameters

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-ide-2

when the Arduino_2 starts the board is not selected.

Is it possible to run a program with such parameters (for example)?: "C:\Program Files\Arduino IDE\Arduino IDE.exe" --board arduino:avr:uno --С:\Users\scetch.ino

Comment: It's not something the Arduino IDE 2.x currently supports. However, the IDE should remember the selected board between IDE stop/start once selected. `File` > `New Sketch` should inherit the board selection from the currently opened sketch window. Please elaborate on why you find this feature helpful besides saving two clicks after the sketch opens. It can be implemented if there is a good reason.